# How do you call the "happy-dog" part of file "happy-dog.png"?

Tags: files, filenames, terminology, basename

I just realized I don't know how `file` is called in `file.ext`.

The whole `file.ext` is called a file or filename, `ext` is called extension but how do you call the `file` part itself of `file.ext`?

For example `happy-dog.png`. All the file/filename is `happy-dog.png`, extension is `png` but how do you call `happy-dog`?

It's not basename. Is it like titlename? Or filepart? Any ideas?

Comment: Why not basename?  There's even a command `basename`:  Try this at your prompt `basename happy-dog.png .png`  or `basename dir/happy-dog.png .png`.

Comment: @RobertL in most shells this will return `happy-dog.png` again, without separating a part.

Comment: @Netch Maybe questioner is correct, it's not basename?  I always thought of it as the base name, but I could be wrong!

Comment: Isn't it suffix and prefix?

Answer (score 4):

I doubt there is a stable terminology here. A small googling exposes people utilize `base name` for this, but this usage conflicts with the same term used as "full file name without path". For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183486/ exposes the case when "filename" is "basename" plus "extension".

OTOH, the term "extension" you use is weird. It's originated in CP-M/Dos/Windows world (distorting imitation of RSX-11/RT-11 approach) where a file name could (before Windows 95) have a single part after dot. In Unix world, this was being named "suffix" from the very beginning, and I would strongly suggest you using this term. The difference is that multiple suffixes can exist - for example, `a.o.d` is dependency list for `a.o`. In turn, if this is suffix, the part before suffixes is a `filename root`. In my opinion, there is too small chance to get it conflicting with "root" as Unix superuser.

UPD: linguistics often use "stem" in a vast sense "part before ending and, sometimes, before suffix". But I see mention for "root" in neighbor reply, so, seems "root" is good until you need further distinction.

Comment: Note that for ODS-2, the on-disk filesystem layout used by the VMS operating system, the "extension" was actually a separate part of the inode-moral-equivalent ("file header", I think). I'm pretty sure that was the case for MS-DOS "FAT" filesystems, and I believe it's still the case for NTFS, which is a whole lot like ODS-2 on disk.

Answer (score 2):

`csh`, `tcsh`,`vim` and `zsh` which have an operator to extract that part of the file name (`$file:r`) call it the *root name* or *root of the file name* (well, `$file:r` applied to `/foo/bar.baz` is `/foo/bar`, so `bar` would rather be the *root of the basename* or the *basename of the root*). `Erlang` also has a [`rootname()`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/filename.html#rootname-1) operator and the [`python` documentation also refers to the file path without the extension as the *root*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext).

That may not be very common practice (I long thought myself *r* was for ***r**est of the file name* and web search engines don't bring up a lot of references) but that's a long-standing one since that feature was already there and documented as such in the first publicly released version of `csh` in 1979.

Answer (score 2):

I quite like [Python's pathlib terminology of stem](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem). This is consistent with natural language processing terminology, but I don't believe this is universal.